# React native adding a logout button to a drawer component with dispatched action integrated with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, navigation-drawer

I am just new to RN. I have a **routes.js** in my config folder where all my **drawerNavigator** and **stackNavigator** is defined. It looked like this.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from "react-navigation";


import Home from "../screens/home";
import Login from "../screens/login";
import DrawerComponent from "../components/drawer"

export const MainStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: Home
}, {
  contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'green'
  }
});

export const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login
  }
});
```

Now everything is working fine in my **routes navigation**, but I want to add a Logout Button in the **drawerNavigator** that doesn't navigate to some page. Instead I want to dispatch a async redux action that will call the function and call an API request. If it success then the user will be redirected to the **LoginStack**

This is my code in **drawer.js** which is a component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerItems } from "react-navigation";

const DrawerComponent = (props) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Image source={{ uri: 'http://i.pravatar.cc/300' }}
                style={{ height: 120, width: 120, borderRadius: 60 }} />
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button title="LOG OUT" onPress={() => this.props.onPress()}/>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)

export default DrawerComponent
```

I am emitting a **onPress prop event** in the button of the logout. So will the **routes.js** will handle that event or some higher order or container component instead?

I had already a existing async redux logout function which is working very well. I used it like this below in my **home.js** screen.

```
<CustomButton onPress={() =>
            this.props.actions.logout(this.props.state.authSession.token)
          } title={"SIGN OUT"} />
```

and in my **connect**

```
export default connect(
  state => ({ state: state.authenticate }),
  dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
  })
)(Home)
```

Now the code that I had showed in my **home.js** is working fine. It logs out the user and redirected to the **loginStack** but I want to transfer it in the **Drawer Component** how do I do it in a proper way?

The main question is where do I handle that `onProps` **press event** of the **Logout Button** in the **DrawerComponent**. The **higher level component** should be the one to handle that **event** to **dispatch** a action right?

Now since I am using the **DrawerComponent** in the **routes.js** file. Should I connect redux in that or no? If not where do I will handle the event. It will be better if you can show some code.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.